# MSS 4.0.21 doesn't proxy CANCEL request

Tags: proxy, sip, restcomm, sip-servlet, mss

I tested Mobicents (RestComm) Sip-Servlet (v 4.0.21) in proxy mode. Request "CANCEL" sent from UAC to UAS via Proxy Server (Apache Tomcat 8.0 + MSS 4.0.21) is not forwarded to UAS. The Sip-Servlet just returns 200 Cancelling to UAC and calls proxy.cancelAllExcept.

What could be reason of such behavior?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

The problem was somewhere related with ipAddress in SIP Connector section of server.xml. It was 0.0.0.0. As soon as I put IP4 returned by ipconfig the sip-servlet behavior became as expected.